# Intersection with MySQL with queries

Tags: mysql

I am trying to intersect two querys in MySQL in this fashion:

```
SELECT user_id FROM post GROUP BY thread_id HAVING COUNT(thread_id) = 1
INTERSECT
SELECT user_id FROM post GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(user_id) = 1;
```

I've looked for ways to do it in MySQL, but unfortunately using IN and INNER JOIN hasn't worked for me.

The test data I'm working with is:

```
insert into post (post_number, timestamp, user_id, thread_id) values(0,0,1,1000);
insert into post (post_number, timestamp, user_id, thread_id) values(0,0,2,2000);
insert into post (post_number, timestamp, user_id, thread_id) values(0,0,3,2000);
insert into post (post_number, timestamp, user_id, thread_id) values(0,0,4,3000);
insert into post (post_number, timestamp, user_id, thread_id) values(0,0,5,4000);
insert into post (post_number, timestamp, user_id, thread_id) values(0,0,1,4000);
```

Running an intersection of my two queries should result in

```
4
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What do you get when you run the query you have?

Comment: The first part of your intersection isn't valid sql: you can't select something you didn't group by. Does that work in MySql? What concept are you expressing with that first statement? Is it select users that have only posted in one thread? Users that are the only poster in thread?

Answer (score 2):

In postgres I'd do it like this

```
SELECT user_id FROM post where thread_id in (
select thread_id from post group by thread_id having count(distinct user_id) = 1)
INTERSECT
SELECT user_id FROM post GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(user_id) = 1;
```

However, apparently mysql doesn't support intersect, so an inner join will suffice:

```
SELECT post.user_id FROM post 
join (SELECT user_id FROM post GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(user_id) = 1) x on x.user_id = post.user_id
where 
post.thread_id in (
select thread_id from post group by thread_id having count(distinct user_id) = 1)
```

Those both return 4

Answer (score 1):

So, you want a list of users who have posted one orphan thread? Maybe a subselect works best.

```
SELECT user_id
  FROM (
    SELECT user_id
      FROM post
      GROUP BY thread_id
      HAVING COUNT(thread_id) = 1
  ) AS orphan
  GROUP BY user_id
  HAVING COUNT(user_id) = 1
```

EDIT: Yeah, the above was wrong; I didn't think about it enough. Here's another go, but don't get your hopes up:

```
SELECT user_id
  FROM (
    SELECT user_id
      FROM post
      GROUP BY thread_id
      HAVING COUNT(thread_id) = 1
  ) AS orphan_post
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id
      FROM post
      GROUP BY user_id
      HAVING COUNT(user_id) = 1
  ) AS orphan_user
  ON user_id
```